# Controlling DC motor speed?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to control a DC motor through L293D motor controller

[image: circuit diagram using L293D motor controller and Arduino]

```
const int controlPin2 = 4; // connected to pin 2 on the H-bridge
    const int enablePin = 3;   // connected to pin 1 on the H-bridge


void setup(){

  pinMode(controlPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(enablePin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Ready");
}


void loop(){
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int inByte = Serial.read();

    switch (inByte) {
    case '0':   
  digitalWrite(enablePin, LOW);
   digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);
 Serial.println("OFF");
      break;
    case '1':   

  digitalWrite(controlPin2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 50);
    Serial.println("CW slow");
      break;
          case '2':   

  digitalWrite(controlPin2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 100);
    Serial.println("CW slow +");
      break;
          case '3':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 150);
    Serial.println("CW medium");
      break;
          case '4':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 200);
    Serial.println("CW fast");
      break;
          case '5':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 250);
    Serial.println("CW fast +");
      break;
    case '6':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 50);
    Serial.println("CCW slow");
      break;
      case '7':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 100);
        Serial.println("CCW slow +");
      break;
      case '8':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 150);
        Serial.println("CCW medium");
      break;
       case '9':   
  digitalWrite(controlPin2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enablePin, 250);
        Serial.println("CCW fast");
      break;
}
}
}
```

It is working well except 1 to 5 are reversed:

- 1 should be the minimum speed
- 5 should be the maximum.

But it is back to front:

- 5 is the minimum speed
- 1 is the maximum speed

Any ideas?

Comment: Other than changing your `case` expressions?

Answer (score 2):

So first thing, you should try to be more disciplined with your code formatting and the question...

FYI: it's best to use #define as it doesn't use memory for storing pin numbers... It's like Find and Replace in a text editor, this:

```
const int controlPin2 = 4; // connected to pin 2 on the H-bridge
const int enablePin = 3;   // connected to pin 1 on the H-bridge
```

Becomes this:

```
#define controlPin2 4  // connected to pin 2 on the H-bridge
#define enablePin   3  // connected to pin 1 on the H-bridge
```

So this is the tidied up code, you can see the problem is a lot more approachable when the code is indented consistently, and good use of spaces and new lines is used...

```
#define controlPin2 4  // connected to pin 2 on the H-bridge
#define enablePin   3  // connected to pin 1 on the H-bridge


void setup () {
    pinMode( controlPin2, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( enablePin, OUTPUT );

    digitalWrite( enablePin, LOW );
    digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );

    Serial.begin( 9600 );
    Serial.println( "Ready" );
}

void loop() {
    if ( Serial.available() > 0) {
        int inByte = Serial.read();

        switch ( inByte ) {

            case '0':
                digitalWrite( enablePin, LOW );
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                Serial.println( "OFF" );
            break;

            case '1':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 50 );
                Serial.println( "CW slow" );
            break;

            case '2':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 100 );
                Serial.println( "CW slow +" );
            break;

            case '3':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 150 );
                Serial.println( "CW medium" );
            break;

            case '4':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 200 );
                Serial.println( "CW fast" );
            break;

            case '5':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 250 );
                Serial.println( "CW fast +" );
            break;

            case '6':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 50 );
                Serial.println( "CCW slow" );
            break;

            case '7':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 100 );
                Serial.println( "CCW slow +" );
            break;

            case '8':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 150 );
                Serial.println( "CCW medium" );
            break;

            case '9':   
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 250 );
                Serial.println( "CCW fast" );
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

So your actual problem is that you need to reverse cases 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to be 5, 4, 3, 2, 1...

There are two solutions:

1. **Inelegant**: would be to simply change the case numbers, they don't have to be in-order.
2. **Elegant**: copy and paste the code in each of the 5 cases about.

The result of option 2 is as follows, please feel free to confirm this is working?

```
#define controlPin2 4  // connected to pin 2 on the H-bridge
#define enablePin   3  // connected to pin 1 on the H-bridge


void setup () {
    pinMode( controlPin2, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( enablePin, OUTPUT );

    digitalWrite( enablePin, LOW );
    digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );

    Serial.begin( 9600 );
    Serial.println( "Ready" );
}

void loop() {
    if ( Serial.available() > 0) {
        int inByte = Serial.read();

        switch ( inByte ) {

            case '0':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 250 );
                Serial.println( "CW fast +" );
            break;

            case '1':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 200 );
                Serial.println( "CW fast" );
            break;

            case '2':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 150 );
                Serial.println( "CW medium" );
            break;

            case '3':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 100 );
                Serial.println( "CW slow +" );
            break;

            case '4':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, HIGH );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 50 );
                Serial.println( "CW slow" );
            break;

            case '5':
                digitalWrite( enablePin, LOW );
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                Serial.println( "OFF" );
            break;

            case '6':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 50 );
                Serial.println( "CCW slow" );
            break;

            case '7':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 100 );
                Serial.println( "CCW slow +" );
            break;

            case '8':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 150 );
                Serial.println( "CCW medium" );
            break;

            case '9':
                digitalWrite( controlPin2, LOW );
                analogWrite( enablePin, 250 );
                Serial.println( "CCW fast" );
            break;

        }
    }
}
```